# Web application : What should I send back to the user?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, rest

I am writing a web application - angularJS in the frontend, REST API and mongodb as the backend. Powered by node.js.

Background to the issue :

I know I need to authenticate my users with token based authentication, and then I need to have the token be available for every new request thereafter. I also need to be able to hold onto the user ID in order to make transactions on the database later.

My main problem with that strategy, is that this means after getting the token back, I need to hold onto the token and the ID after login, and because I am building a web front end, I am storing these in localStorage.

Any user who might be malicious may choose to dump data from that store, and see what value they could change to get at other people's data, right in their browser's dev tools!

This has to be something that can be fixed, and I know some of you will have addressed this in the past. So what do we do in this scenario?

Maybe there is a way to do this in a more secure fashion? Or maybe I don't need to store them at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any user who might be malicious may choose to dump data from that
>   store, and see what value they could change to get at other people's
>   data, right in their browser's dev tools!

Really? You should authorize requests based on user owning the access token, thus, if the whole user goes to any in-browser debugging tool and gets the token, that user will be able to do nothing more than what could do from the UI.

In the other hand, you don't need to hold an user id. That user id should be part of the access token once the whole user gets authorized in your system, and only the server should be able to work with it.

The so-called access token can be stored as an encrypted word in a Web browser cookie, which is better than local storage because cookies are being send as part of any HTTP request either regular or AJAX one (i.e. *you don't need to include the token manually whenever you want to perform a request to your API*), and during server authorization process, you should unencrypt the token and get back its info (usually called *claims*).

Comment: and that is EXACTLY the information I needed! Thanks :)